# Lines on Fano complete intersections

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, fano-varieties

Let $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ be a non-singular complete intersection of $s$ hypersurfaces
of degrees $d_1,\dots,d_s$ over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic zero. Let $d=d_1 + \dots + d_s$.
Suppose that $X$ is Fano, i.e. $d < n + 1$. Denote by $F_1(X)$ the Fano variety of lines in $X$. Then it is known that if $X$ is *general*, then one has

$$\dim F_1(X) = 2n - d - s - 2 \quad (*),$$

if this number is non-negative. Moreover, a conjecture of Debarre and de Jong states that $(*)$ holds for all such $X$ (not necessarily general) if $s=1$, i.e. if $X$ is a hypersurface. I have only seen this conjecture stated for hypersurfaces. My question is what happens for complete intersections.

> > Is $(*)$ still expected to hold for all such $X$ (not necessarily general) if $s >1$?

Perhaps this is dealt with in the original article where Debarre and de Jong made this conjecture, however I have been unable to find it, only other papers (not by Debarre and de Jong) which state this conjecture (without reference).

Comment: Your formula (*) is wrong.  It should be $2n-d-s-2$.

Comment: @Jason: You are quite right, thank you.

Comment: I guess the first test case is whether a complete intersection of $s=2t$ quadrics in $\mathbb{P}^{4t}$ can contain a 1-parameter family of linear $\mathbb{P}^t$s.  For hypersurfaces, independently, Debarre and I proved this cannot happen (my argument is in an appendix to an article of Browning and Heath-Brown).  Perhaps the same argument would apply in this case.  At any rate, I am unaware of anybody investigating this.  It sounds like a great project!

Comment: Thanks for your comments Jason. I won't deny when I put this on mathoverflow I was hoping you would see it... Is there an original paper by Debarre and/or de Jong where they state this conjecture, or is it more of a word-of-mouth conjecture?

Comment: Actually I recommend checking with Roya Beheshti at Washington University.  She knows much more about this than I do.